# pass control to user for specified amount of time

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that runs a command prompt if an executable is available.  The macro waits 5 minutes before checking to see if an executable is available.  The problem is that this locks excel.  What I would prefer to do is pass control back to the user for five minutes.

This is what the bit of code looks like at the moment.

```
Do Until TuflowEx < Range("Exe").Value ' Check if number of executables running is less than the user specified maximum
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:05:00")) ' Wait 5 minutes before checking again
    TuflowEx = TuEx() ' Run TuEx to get the currently active number of executables
Loop
```

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Application.Ontime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196165.aspx) instead.

Just create a routine to do the check, and have it resume your logic if the check succeeds.

```
Sub ChecktuflowEx()
    If TuEx() => Range("Exe").Value Then
        'whatever you want
    Else
        'Check again in 5 minutes.
        Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("0:05:00"), "ChecktuflowEx"
    End If
End Sub
```